# Copy Paste random number results

Tags: vba

```
Sub MinimumCost()
Range("TotalCost_D").ClearContents

Range("MinimumCost").Value = 100000000
Dim i As Integer

Range("PurchasedVans_M").Formula = "=Randbetween(0,2)"

For i = 1 To 10000

Calculate

If Range("TotalCost").Value < Range("MinimumCost").Value Then
Range("MinimumCost").Value = Range("TotalCost").Value
    Range("TotalCost_D") = Range("MinimumCost")
    Range("PurchasedVans").Value = Range("PurchasedVans_M").Value

    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

The code intends to calculate optimisation cost and then past the optimised number of van and cost into the dashboard.

The problem is that the number of van is not matched the optimisation cost result. This means I used the number of vans purchased results to calculate total cost which is not equal the optimisaion cost I got previously. 
Is because random between function cannot be fixed?
Is any better way to generate random number?
Could you please check my code and tell me the reason of the problem?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

RandBetween will recalculate every time you invoke Calculate, i.e. 10,000 times.

If you want it to be calculated just once per call to MinimumCost, then replace the formula with a value:

```
    Range("PurchasedVans_M").Value = Int(Rnd * 3)
```

The Excel function `RandBetween(a,b)` is equivalent to VBA `Int(a + Rnd * (b - a + 1))`

Be aware that RandBetween(0,2) returns an ***integer***  0, 1 or 2.

If you want a ***floating-point*** number `0 <= n < 2` then use `Rnd * 2`.

The more general case of `a <= n < b` would be `a + Rnd * (b - a)`